Curl Receiving an access token OAuth2
I have been trying to setup an API to my departments scheduling tool.
I am having a hard time following the documentation since i've never used CURL.
I have the Client ID and the Client Secret key.
This is what the documentation shows:
Receiving an access token:
 curl -v https://api.crewsense.com/oauth/access_token \
 -d "client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID" \
 -d "client_secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY" \
 -d "grant_type=client_credentials"

I have tried to enter that on my command prompt with no luck, also tried on a site that runs commands online and I get some errors.
Is the syntax not correct? do I need something else? Do I need quotation marks when entering mt ID and Key?
Or should I not be running that on CMD.
Any help is appreciated.
Also this is what the documentation explains should happen after.
If the request is successful and you credentials are correct, you should receive a JSON response like this:
{
"access_token": "DZs3IeaMP5uEAc2I19kJYl8Tbvsmgq9GaPQPaMjN",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires": 1426274440,
"expires_in": 86400
}

Thank you in advance.
Tried pasting the code on the browser and on the command line with no luck

You said what you tried, but you didn't explain how the request fails. As a rule of thumb, if you ever get an error you need include that error when asking questions.

You need to send a POST request to the token endpoint. You should also indicate a form URL encoded content type and typically also request a specific scope that the target API requires.
Try this command and double check that you have the correct URL against your provider's documentation.
curl -k -X POST https://api.crewsense.com/oauth/access_token \
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
-d "client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID" \
-d "client_secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY" \
-d "grant_type=client_credentials \
-d "scope=myscope"

